# Do you have to have com. or uk.co. in your package name

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm really struggling to link google play services to an app I am publishing. I am speculating if a problem is because I do no have a com. on the package.

In other words, my package is:
mycompany.myapp

as opposed to: 
uk.co.mycompany.myapp

Will this matter or is this not actually an issue?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *.com* or the *.co.uk* doesn't matter, it can be *my.super.duper.app.here*, as long as no other app uses it. You can find more information naming a package [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html).

Either way, it shouldn't make a difference as long as your package name is unique (that is why people usually use domain names).

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up. Lots of post discussed how to name but i simply wanted to know if id made a mistake. Thank you.

Comment: @TBQPR No problem! If this answered your question, remember to click the checkmark below the Up & Down votes. It marks the answer as correct.

Comment: I have tried to upmark but my reputation isnt good enough. I will upmark when it is good enough. Thanks again

Comment: Great, thanks! This link should show you how to do it if you are having trouble: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235